# Something like jQuery.ready(fn) for Backbone collections and models

Tags: events, backbone.js, asynchronous

I have a preloaded object graph of Backbone collections and models. To initialize my UI I need to make sure the collections are loaded, and then pull some item from them by ID using `get()`. I want to have a method that accepts a callback which is either called immediately if the collection is loaded, or gets delayed until the collection is loaded.

So far I have the following abomination of a mixin:

```
window.BackboneReady =
  onReady: (cb)->
    if @loaded_
      console.log "Calling onReady immediately"
      cb(@)
    else
      console.log "Scheduling onReady for later"
      @once 'sync', =>
        console.log "onReady fired in callback"
        @loaded_ = true
        cb(@)
```

however, it only works sometimes (I see the message "Scheduling onReady for later" but my event handler is never executed). Rant: it looks Backbone doesn't even have a basic signal variable to tell me whether the object is synced or not, which seems completely absurd.

What would be the sane way to accomplish this? I don't want to call `fetch()` every time I want to `get()` an object from the collection for my UI since this defeats the purpose of holding a preloaded object graph in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your collection to use promises and solve your challenge

```
initialize: function(){
  this.on("request", function(collection, xhr, options){
      this.ready = xhr;
  });
}
```

Then you can do

```
$.when(myCollection.ready).done(function(){
   // do things to the collection that is ready
   console.log(myCollection.get(5));
});
```

Or in your collection:

```
getIfLoaded: function(id){
  if(this.ready.state === "resolved"){
    return this.get(id);
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

For more info on deferred and promises, take a look at http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/ and http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/02/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-async-functions-return-using-promises/

Comment: I am already using this approach, but I need to do a `Collection#get()` which does not do promise wrapping - it just gives me `undefined` if the item hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: You can either do that in the `done` callback as above (I edited my anser), or implement something like the `getIfLoaded` above.

Comment: This is what I ended up with, thanks. Maybe I just have to split the promise steps for 'fetch()` and `get()` and do a `get()` only when all of the `fetch()` promises for the current app state are `done()` - tack it on in `then()`